# Out of heap memory with k-means on large data set

Tags: java, out-of-memory, k-means

I am using k-means algorithm for data clustering and using large data set. I have almost 100000 research papers and I want to cluster them by using k-means. I am using traditional k-means and also by using inverted index but in both programs. When I put 50000 I gets out of heap memory in Java (using NetBeans).

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class kmeans
{
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException
    {
        //read in documents from all .txt files in same folder as kmeans.java
        //save parallel lists of documents (String[]) and their filenames, and create global set list of words
        ArrayList<String[]> docs = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        ArrayList<String> filenames = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> global = new ArrayList<String>();
        File folder = new File(".");
        List<File> files = Arrays.asList(folder.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File f) {
                return f.isFile() && f.getName().endsWith(".txt");
            }
        }));
        BufferedReader in = null;
        for(File f:files){
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String s = null;
            while((s = in.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(s);
            }
            //input cleaning regex
            String[] d = sb.toString().replaceAll("[\\W&&[^\\s]]","").split("\\W+");
            for(String u:d)
                if(!global.contains(u))
                    global.add(u);
            docs.add(d);
            filenames.add(f.getName());
        }
        //

        //compute tf-idf and create document vectors (double[])
        ArrayList<double[]> vecspace = new ArrayList<double[]>();
        for(String[] s:docs){
            double[] d = new double[global.size()];
            for(int i=0;i<global.size();i++)
                d[i] = tf(s,global.get(i)) * idf(docs,global.get(i));
            vecspace.add(d);
        }

        //iterate k-means
        HashMap<double[],TreeSet<Integer>> clusters = new HashMap<double[],TreeSet<Integer>>();
        HashMap<double[],TreeSet<Integer>> step = new HashMap<double[],TreeSet<Integer>>();
        HashSet<Integer> rand = new HashSet<Integer>();
        TreeMap<Double,HashMap<double[],TreeSet<Integer>>> errorsums = new TreeMap<Double,HashMap<double[],TreeSet<Integer>>>();
        int k = 3;
        int maxiter = 500;
        for(int init=0;init<100;init++){
            clusters.clear();
            step.clear();
            rand.clear();
            //randomly initialize cluster centers
            while(rand.size()< k)
                rand.add((int)(Math.random()*vecspace.size()));
            for(int r:rand){
                double[] temp = new double[vecspace.get(r).length];
                System.arraycopy(vecspace.get(r),0,temp,0,temp.length);
                step.put(temp,new TreeSet<Integer>());
            }
            boolean go = true;
            int iter = 0;
            while(go){
                clusters = new HashMap<double[],TreeSet<Integer>>(step);
                //cluster assignment step
                for(int i=0;i<vecspace.size();i++){
                    double[] cent = null;
                    double sim = 0;
                    for(double[] c:clusters.keySet()){
                        double csim = cosSim(vecspace.get(i),c);
                        if(csim > sim){
                            sim = csim;
                            cent = c;
                        }
                    }
                    clusters.get(cent).add(i);
                }
                //centroid update step
                step.clear();
                for(double[] cent:clusters.keySet()){
                    double[] updatec = new double[cent.length];
                    for(int d:clusters.get(cent)){
                        double[] doc = vecspace.get(d);
                        for(int i=0;i<updatec.length;i++)
                            updatec[i]+=doc[i];
                    }
                    for(int i=0;i<updatec.length;i++)
                        updatec[i]/=clusters.get(cent).size();
                    step.put(updatec,new TreeSet<Integer>());
                }
                //check break conditions
                String oldcent="", newcent="";
                for(double[] x:clusters.keySet())
                    oldcent+=Arrays.toString(x);
                for(double[] x:step.keySet())
                    newcent+=Arrays.toString(x);
                if(oldcent.equals(newcent)) go = false;
                if(++iter >= maxiter) go = false;
            }
            System.out.println(clusters.toString().replaceAll("\\[[\\w@]+=",""));
            if(iter<maxiter)
                System.out.println("Converged in "+iter+" steps.");
            else System.out.println("Stopped after "+maxiter+" iterations.");
            System.out.println("");

            //calculate similarity sum and map it to the clustering
            double sumsim = 0;
            for(double[] c:clusters.keySet()){
                    TreeSet<Integer> cl = clusters.get(c);
                    for(int vi:cl){
                        sumsim+=cosSim(c,vecspace.get(vi));
                    }
                }
            errorsums.put(sumsim,new HashMap<double[],TreeSet<Integer>>(clusters));

        }
        //pick the clustering with the maximum similarity sum and print the filenames and indices
        System.out.println("Best Convergence:");
        System.out.println(errorsums.get(errorsums.lastKey()).toString().replaceAll("\\[[\\w@]+=",""));
        System.out.print("{");
        for(double[] cent:errorsums.get(errorsums.lastKey()).keySet()){
            System.out.print("[");
            for(int pts:errorsums.get(errorsums.lastKey()).get(cent)){
                System.out.print(filenames.get(pts).substring(0,filenames.get(pts).lastIndexOf(".txt"))+", ");
            }
            System.out.print("\b\b], ");
        }
        System.out.println("\b\b}");
    }

    static double cosSim(double[] a, double[] b){
        double dotp=0, maga=0, magb=0;
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            dotp+=a[i]*b[i];
            maga+=Math.pow(a[i],2);
            magb+=Math.pow(b[i],2);
        }
        maga = Math.sqrt(maga);
        magb = Math.sqrt(magb);
        double d = dotp / (maga * magb);
        return d==Double.NaN?0:d;
    }

    static double tf(String[] doc, String term){
        double n = 0;
        for(String s:doc)
            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(term))
                n++;
        return n/doc.length;
    }

    static double idf(ArrayList<String[]> docs, String term){
        double n = 0;
        for(String[] x:docs)
            for(String s:x)
                if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(term)){
                    n++;
                    break;
                }
        return Math.log(docs.size()/n);
    }
}
```

Comment: You described a problem, but what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the amount of heap memory using -Xmx... as a command line argument for java.exe; e.g. -Xmx1024m to set the maximum heap size to 1024Mb.

Comment: 100,000 * 700 (average length in words of paper) * 5 (about average length of word) * 32 (unicode 32) ~= 10 GB only for the strings. This of course does not include overhead for 70,000,000 objects for the different words stored. some optimizations MUST be made, and it also might not be enough (could be needing a cluster for it)

Comment: 100,000 * 700 (average length in words of paper) * 5 (about average length of word) * 4 (unicode 32) ~= 2.5 GB

Answer (score 0):

You'd rather used Lucene index and make use of TermFreqs and TermFreqVectors and calculate cosine similarity from index. This will reduce your processing time and memory problem. You should give a try.